# I Can't get Move module keys working, I can't chose them

Tags: pygame

I'm making a module to make moving rects easier, but I cant get a part of it to work,
i want to be able to name the keys it uses but I can't seem to get that to work, heres my code:

```
import pygame

#this is where i would have i find out what keys the user want's to use
#The k1,k2,k3,k4s
def move(rect, vel, k1,k2,k3,k4):
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_k1]:
        rect.x -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_k2]:
        rect.x += vel
    if keys[pygame.K_k3]:
        rect.y -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_k4]:
        rect.y += vel

screen= pygame.display.set_mode([500,500])

running =  True
red = pygame.Rect(225,225,50,50)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while running:
    screen.fill([255,255,255])
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,[255,0,0],red)
    pygame.display.flip()
    move(red,10,"a","d","w","s")
    #ADWS being the keys i want to use to move
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            running = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `get_pressed()` method returns an array of ascii values for keys currently pressed. Since it is standard ascii, the user can enter the keys for left\right\up\down and the script can convert them to ascii using the `ord` function.

Try this code:

```
import pygame

keylst = input('Enter Keys to use (Left Right Up Down)').lower() # enter> a d w s

kLeft, kRight, kUp, kDown = (ord(k) for k in keylst.split())  # ascii codes, split on space

#this is where i would have i find out what keys the user want's to use
#The k1,k2,k3,k4s
def move(rect, vel):
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[kLeft]:
        rect.x -= vel
    if keys[kRight]:
        rect.x += vel
    if keys[kUp]:
        rect.y -= vel
    if keys[kDown]:
        rect.y += vel

screen= pygame.display.set_mode([500,500])

running =  True
red = pygame.Rect(225,225,50,50)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while running:
    screen.fill([255,255,255])
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,[255,0,0],red)
    pygame.display.flip()
    move(red,1)
    #ADWS being the keys i want to use to move
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            running = False
```